# Datatables show no data available in the table

Tags: angularjs, datatables

Can someone help me on this matter? Here are my codes:

```
<div class="modal-body no-padding" style="overflow-y: scroll; max-height: 500px;">
        <table width="auto" class="table report-table table-star" id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="center">#</td>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email / Mobile</th>
                <th>Date / Time</th>
                <th>Excellent</th>
                <th>Good</th>
                <th>Average</th>
                <th>Bad</th>
                <th>Worse</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

            <tr ng-repeat="u in user_report">
                <td class="center">{{$index+1}}</td>
                <td>{{u.name}}</td>
                <td>{{u.email}} / {{u.mobile}}</td>
                <td>{{u.timestamp}}</td>
                <td class="center">
                    <span ng-if="u.choice == 1"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>
                    <span ng-if="u.choice != 1"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
                </td>
                <td class="center">
                    <span ng-if="u.choice == 2"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>
                    <span ng-if="u.choice != 2"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
                </td>
                <td class="center">
                    <span ng-if="u.choice == 3"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>
                    <span ng-if="u.choice != 3"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
                </td>
                <td class="center">
                    <span ng-if="u.choice == 4"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>
                    <span ng-if="u.choice != 4"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
                </td>
                <td class="center">
                    <span ng-if="u.choice == 5"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></span>
                    <span ng-if="u.choice != 5"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
  </div>
```

And the script below the html to call the datatable:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() {$('#example').DataTable();} );</script>
```

By the way, it show the data but there is "No data available in the table" message on the last row. Once I click on the sorting / pagination, the data gone out from the table.

Comment: This is probably a race condition. `DataTable()` is running before AngularJS has rendered the DOM from your data. Find the moment your data is done being fetched (presumably in the success callback of an AJAX call), and use $timeout($("#example").DataTable()), which will make sure it doesn't run until the next digest cycle.

Comment: As an aside, unless these are very small bits of data, try not to use DataTables with AngularJS, as they both manage their own internal states of the table data, resulting in bloated memory usage and potential performance issues. If you need AngularJS, consider using the venerable http://ui-grid.info/ or some jQuery grid with AngularJS support like Kendo UI's grid.

Comment: @JacobStamm thanks.. I think so.. that (document).ready(function() can never work with AngularJS. I might need to try ui-grid for tabling purpose. Thanks for your useful comment.